# Sales and Profits Charts for Tableau

Tags: charts, tableau-api

I have seen a chart for sales and profits. However, I am not sure how to use my values to make it. 
The example I have found is the picture below:[image]

The value I have now are: 
Products, profit, profit ratio, sales and date, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can drag the sales measure to columns, the profit measure to rows and get a scatter plot. This will probably only give you one point. You will probably want to detail over some other property. You could for example bring in 'Products' in detail to get a similar result.

What the picture also shows is the tooltip for a 'Maria Etezadi'. 
I believe what you miss here is an additional data source containing persons. You can try to find this, bring it in and then join the two data sources. This Maria is probably inside this second source. If you drag the names into the detail box you might get something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! May I know what is the name for the chart(what kind of chart) for the picture on top?

Comment: This is a scatter plot. But normally tableau will automatically detect this when you drag sales to columns and profit to rows.

Comment: The scatter plot is Tableau's recommendation anytime you select two measures